Why is my AMP-form in gmail inbox alway returning a submit-error
I have an AMP email template that is working correctly when previewing in my browser, but not when sending myself tests to my gmail inbox via https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/. Note: I do have amp@gmail.dev whitelisted and I am receiving the amp email tests.
The browser preview can be seen here (AMP section near the bottom): https://mailpreview.net/fc/376eaddf/r716853-01e9b614/email-amp.html
The inbox preview can be seen in this screenshot.enter image description here
I believe I've identified the issue as related to the submit result of the form.
meaning, in the browser the form results in a "submit-success", whereas in the email inbox the form results in a "submit-error".
I'm not sure how much code I can share without stackoverflow thinking this is spam, but I am willing to share as much code of the email as is helpful including the header tags and the specific form code.
I tried testing my email using two methods.

First, I reviewed the html file in my chrome browser - this results in a successful test with the expected text showing after submitting the AMP-form
Second, I used https://amp.gmail.dev/playground/ to send myself a test to my gmail inbox - filling out the AMP-form in the inbox results in no text being displayed


Please share a valid AMP HTML that reproduces the issue and/or share the JS console error when submitting the form. When I tried to copy https://mailpreview.net/fc/376eaddf/r716853-01e9b614/email-amp.html into the playground there are AMP validation errors. It appears that https://mailpreview.net/fc/376eaddf/r716853-01e9b614/email-amp.html is just a template and needs to be populated to produce the actual valid AMP HTML. The JS console error will tell us why the XHR failed.

@SuZhang thank you! There's probably an easier way to share the full html, but here's a doc I created with the full HTML that I've been sending myself through amp.gmail.dev/playground. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1575N7eL9r4UsuSi8BZa0gQ2Lv-xLtrRDDMQe15Aldes/edit?usp=sharing

I tried your sample AMP HTML in Gmail and here's what I got in the JS console:
amp-form] Form submission failed: Error: Request viewerRenderTemplate failed: Error: Class$obf_1009: Access to fetch at 'https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/api/echo' from source origin 'amp@gmail.dev' has been blocked by AMP CORS policy: no 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' header is present on the requested resource

I also tried your sample AMP HTML in the Gmail AMP playground (https://amp.gmail.dev) and got this:
Request xhr failed: The amp-access-control-allow-source-origin must be equal to the amp source origin sent in the request.​​​

Both errors are related to AMP CORS. This is because the XHR endpoint you are using https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/api/echo does not respond with the necessary CORS and AMP CORS headers for XHRs to work in AMP emails. Please see https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/email/learn/cors-in-email for more details on how XHR endpoints should behave.
https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/api/echo might be an endpoint used only by AMP for Website samples, not emails. Note that the regular AMP playground (https://playground.amp.dev) simulates less about real AMP email behaviors than the Gmail AMP playground, which is why the sample may work in the regular AMP playground but not the Gmail playground or within the Gmail UI.

Thank you for this answer. Although I haven't fully resolved the issue yet, It has helped me identify the xhr as the issue.
